# How to get chart snapshot/image from TradingView with indicators for a selected pair through API?

Tags: tradingview-api

How do you get chart snapshot/image from TradingView with indicators for a selected pair through API?

I have checked their documentation obviously but there is nothing mentioning how to take snapshots. Using widget is not an option for me, I need the images (I will use it for telegram bot)